# C# linq Element-Wise sum of List of List<int>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a one or more lists of int of the same length. I would like to combine them into a new list that sums them *by index*:

```
    var a = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1 };
    var b = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1 };
    var c = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5 };
   //or more lists
   
    expected = {5, 6, 7}; // == { 1 + 1 + 3, 1 + 1 + 4, 1 + 1 + 5}
```

Comment: Do you mean sum of each list or sum of matching indexes from all 3 lists?

Comment: updated example to show better....but a matching index sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have *several* list, you can *organize* them into a *collection* and *query* this collection with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...
// collection (let it be list) instead of separate variables a, b, c
// If lists have unequal number of items, I use 0 instead of abscent item 
var lists = new List<List<int>>() {
  new List<int>() {1, 2, 3},
  new List<int>() {1, 2, 1},
  new List<int>() {1, 4, 3},
};

...

// {3, 8, 7} == { 1 + 1 + 1, 2 + 2 + 4, 3 + 1 + 3 }
List<int> expected = Enumerable
  .Range(0, lists.Max(item => item.Count))
  .Select(index => lists.Sum(item => item.ElementAtOrDefault(index))) 
  .ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sEZjkk)

if you want `a, b, c` you can put

```
var a = lists[0];
var b = lists[1];
var c = lists[2];
```

Comment: I would like to sum the lists by their index. I have updated the example to make it more clear, thanks!

Comment: @jriggs: I see; you can try very same idea - organizing lists into a collection and Linq query - but with different query. Please, see my edit